How to solve Null pointer Exception global timeout in Jenkins
FATAL: null
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at hudson.plugins.build_timeout.global.GlobalTimeOutRunListener.setUpEnvironment(GlobalTimeOutRunListener.java:41)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.createLauncher(AbstractBuild.java:617)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:485)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1900)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
    ERROR: Step ‘Allure Report’ failed: no workspace for upgradeStg_CES #41
    [htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
    ERROR: Build step failed with exception
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at htmlpublisher.HtmlPublisher.publishReports(HtmlPublisher.java:235)
        at htmlpublisher.HtmlPublisher.perform(HtmlPublisher.java:199)
        at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:818)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:767)
        at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:179)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:711)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1925)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceCo

ntroller.java:101)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
Build step 'Publish HTML reports' marked build as failure
ERROR: Step ‘Publish TestNG Results’ failed: no workspace for
Email was triggered for: Always.
Sending email for trigger: Always.
ERROR: Error: No workspace found!
    I tried increased global time global configuration in Jenkins.

